# how to get frames with timestamp where frames are converted from video in python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I want to convert video into the frames before feeding it to the classification model. So I need frames on every unique timestamp converted from video here timestamp is the seconds in the video. The following code from opencv lets me convert for every 10 capturing of the frames but I need the timestamp of each frame in the video. Please let me know thanks

```
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('testing.mp4');
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True

while success:
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    print('read a new frame:',success)
    if count%10 == 0 :
         cv2.imwrite('frame%d.jpg'%count,image)
         print('success')
    count+=1
```

Comment: There exists a time elapsed function. Look here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#aeb1644641842e6b104f244f049648f94

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here first we have to get the FPS of the video and then capture the frames using opencv by incrementing the count variable. Then count variable/ fps of the video gives the time stamp of each frames in the video.

```
import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('testing.mp4')
fps = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True

    while success:
        success,frame = vidcap.read()
        count+=1
        print("time stamp current frame:",count/fps)
```

Comment: Had a doubt, how exactly is it different from CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC (https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) ?

Comment: CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC is a direct computation based on CAP_PROP_FPS x frame_idx in video. One should (Please, this has caused me untold hours of suffering) that any CV2 based notion of timestamp is not exactly correct as many cameras such as IP cameras do not have an exactly fixed frame rate but rather report a Nominal frame rate. Thus, the timestamp is naively generated based on the nominal framerate. The actual time of generation for the frame differs from this, which is important if you want to, say, synchronize the motion of objects moving relatively fast.